# HTML / PHP :how do I highlight the number searched in multiplication table that i generated?

Tags: php, html, search

HTML

```
    <form method="GET">
            <b><th>Enter rows: </th>
            <input type="number" name="row"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <th>Enter columns: </th>
            <input type="number" name="column"/></b>
            <br>
            <br>
        <input type="submit" name="generate" value="GENERATE">
        <br><br>
    </form>
```

---

this is the PHP code.
I'm using the "for loop" structure for the multiplication table but I don't know how to highlight the searched number inside the multiplication table. I'm still working on the search.

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['generate']))
        {
            echo "<b>";
                echo "<table name='tab' border='1'>";
                        $rows = $_GET['row'];
                        $columns = $_GET['column'];
                        for ($row =1; $row <= $rows; $row++)
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            for ($column = 1; $column <= $columns; $column++)
                            {
                                echo "<td>" . $column * $row ."</td>";
                            }
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                echo "</table>";
            echo "</b><br><br>";
            echo "<form method='GET'>";
            echo "<div class='mid'><b><th>Search: </th>";
            echo "<input type='number' name='searchbar'/></div>";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='search' value='SEARCH'>";
            echo "<br><br>";
            echo "</form>";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: why not do all this in javascript? also, you don't need to echo every line

Comment: Where is the searched number? Is it one of the products or one of the factors, or both? What have you tried? Seems like a couple of simple `if` statements will do. You already know how to get the searched number.

Comment: thank you :) @LawrenceCherone i deleted all the echo and replace a ( . ) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```
<?php
    $searchbar = isset($_POST["searchbar"]) ? intval($_POST["searchbar"]) : "0";
    $rows = isset($_GET["row"]) ? intval($_GET["row"]) : "0";
    $columns = isset($_GET["column"]) ? intval($_GET["column"]) : "0";
    if(isset($_GET['generate']))
    {
        echo "<table name='tab' border='1'>";
        for ($row =1; $row <= $rows; $row++)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            for ($column = 1; $column <= $columns; $column++)
            {
                $highlight = ($searchbar == $column * $row);
                echo "<td ".($highlight ? 'style="background: red;"' : "")."><b>" . $column * $row ."</b></td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "<form method='POST'>";
        echo "<div class='mid'><b>Search: </b>";
        echo "<input type='number' name='searchbar' value='$searchbar'/></div>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='search' value='SEARCH'>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
    die();
?>
```

First of all, if you use GET as attribute of the tag form, during the submission, you will lost the `generate`, `row` and `column` parameters. If you want to use method GET you have to populate 3 input type hidden (Example: `<input type="hidden" name="column" value="8">`) inside the form for every parameter you want to retain.

So you can try also with this code:

```
<?php
    $searchbar = isset($_GET["searchbar"]) ? intval($_GET["searchbar"]) : "0";
    $rows = isset($_GET["row"]) ? intval($_GET["row"]) : "0";
    $columns = isset($_GET["column"]) ? intval($_GET["column"]) : "0";
    if(isset($_GET['generate']))
    {
        echo "<table name='tab' border='1'>";
                for ($row = 1; $row <= $rows; $row++)
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    for ($column = 1; $column <= $columns; $column++)
                    {
                        $highlight = ($searchbar == $column * $row);
                        echo "<td ".($highlight ? 'style="background: red;"' : "")."><b>" . $column * $row ."</b></td>";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "<form method='GET'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='generate' value='1'/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='row' value='$rows'/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='column' value='$columns'/>";
        echo "<div class='mid'><b>Search: </b>";
        echo "<input type='number' name='searchbar' value='$searchbar'/></div>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='search' value='SEARCH'>";
        echo "<br><br>";
        echo "</form>";
    }
?>
```

Using method POST the url remains the same and you can transfer the `searchbar` parameter after the submit. Inside the loop you can check the `searchbar` value with the generated numbers and highlight the correct number.

Comment: how do i put it all in the center?
the input boxes / the buttons / search ?
i did put the multiplication table at the center, but I don't know how to the other input / text and buttons. please teach me how. :) 
thank you for answering my problem <3

Comment: If you want to center every elements to the center of the page you can add a stylesheet css to it.
Try to add this code inside `<head></head>` tag: `<style type="text/css">body { text-align: center; } table { margin: 0 auto; }</style>`

Comment: ... and in case my answer has solved your problem, could you please accept it as correct?

Comment: how do i accept it as correct ? sorry I'm new here :/

Comment: alright... done accepting the answer :D . anyways the body text align works too! thanks a lot !